# Why are the cabin chimes one semitone lower on the Boeing 747-400 than on other aircraft?

Tags: commercial-aviation, boeing-747, noise

I noticed that the cabin chimes on the Boeing 747-400 overall sound one semitone lower than on other aircraft, including the 737, 777, Airbus A320, and even the 747-8. The same semitone-lower chimes are used on the Bombardier Q400, but that was built later.

Notice [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uym1HSXfx4) that with the exception of some Qatar Airways planes using the "high" chime instead of the "low" chime for the seat belt sign, all the "low" chimes sound the same, with the exception of the Bombardier Q400. That chime is the same as [the one on the Boeing 747-400](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6K4ewwle-cY).

Why is this the case?

Update: I noticed that this question was marked as being primarily based on opinions. However, it's not based on opinions. If you looked at the video links I supplied above, it is a *fact* that the cabin chimes on the 747-400 are lower-pitched than most other planes. All of the planes in the compilation video, except one, are at the same higher pitch. It's *not* just my opinion that they're lower-pitched. Also, if the answer is that "the chime manufacturer simply built it that way", that should be an answer. Questions shouldn't be closed based on the *answer*, the merits of the question *alone* should be judged.

Comment: You realize that there is no standardization for these tones and they can differ by manufacturer and model. They can even differ by operator...

Comment: [Obligatory Fawlty Towers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlE47GckHRA&feature=youtu.be&t=93): "the fire bell is a different; it's a semitone higher"

Comment: A born skill known as a "perfect pitch" is required to hear a semitone difference for the single, randomly sounded tone. Not even every professional musician can do. Most people can only tell the difference between the two that sounded very recently.

Comment: I work for a company that makes such a chime and I can tell you that manufacturing tolerances amongst components in the circuit play a part.  I don't think there is a rigid specification for this either.

Comment: In the compilation video, the chimes are all the same note except for the dash 8 Q400, which is a minor second below the rest, and the 787-800, which is a minor third above the rest.  However, the video for the 747-400 is from a flight simulator, which should not be considered definitive.

Comment: @WayneConrad I can confirm that every 747-400 I've flown has the *exact* same chime that is featured in the simulator video, down to the mechanical characteristics of the chime, having flown on that plane so many times. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a video where someone recorded the seat belt chime like the compilation, so I linked to this one instead.

Comment: The pitch also depends on the the original video footage's FPS (frames per second). A 24fps video played at 25fps would have a higher pitch than originally recorded. On top of that you can add qualitative differences between recording devices and variations due to different video/audio encodings and conversions.

Comment: @rainbowtableturner The videos are all being played at their original frame rate, and I can tell from having flown on 747s and other aircraft so many times that the chimes shown in the videos are the same as those in real life. That said, I'll later publish some analysis that more clearly shows the difference.